# What is the correct way to use smart pointers with CMFCPropertyGridProperty?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, smart-pointers

What is the correct way for using smart pointers with property grid controls so that I don't have to use `new`?

For example:

```
auto AddSection = [](CMFCPropertyGridCtrl *pGrid, CString strSection) -> CMFCPropertyGridProperty*
{
    CMFCPropertyGridProperty* pSection = nullptr;
    pSection = new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(strSection);
    pGrid->AddProperty(pSection);

    return pSection;
};
```

What is the right way to correct this?

Comment: You can't mix normal pointers and smart pointers. AddProperty takes a normal pointer, using an additional smart pointer would corrupt the logic.

Comment: @xMRi Alright, so ignore or suppress the code analysis warning.

Comment: Presumably, the control is part of a dialog that's backed by a `CDialog`-derived class. In that case, make those properties class members, and pass pointers to them to the `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl`. This makes sure that the properties live for as long as the control does, and get properly cleaned up when the dialog destructs.

Comment: @IInspectable They are in a dialog. It is not clear if the grid control takes ownership of the passed in pointer. I think it might.

Comment: As ambiguous as the documentation is, it's *extremely* unlikely for the control to take ownership. With ownership comes the responsibility to release resources, and the control has no way of knowing how to destroy any given `CMFCPropertyGridProperty`. Besides, the documentation for `AddProperty()` notes that client code needs to make sure that the properties outlive the control; a strong indication that the control merely "borrows" the pointers, and ownership remains with the client.

Comment: @IInspectable See: https://nibuthomas.wordpress.com/mfc-feature-pack-tutorial-part-3-cmfcpropertygridctrl/ No need to delete. Explains why I have no memory leaks in debug build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in the MFC source. The code for both `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl` and `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` is contained in file *afxpropertygridctrl.cpp*.

`CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::AddProperty()` takes a `CMFCPropertyGridProperty*` argument and adds it to the list of properties (`m_lstProps`). It's a normal pointer, not a smart one. It also calls the protected method `SetOwnerList()` which appears to bind it to the grid control items.

And there is also the `RemoveAll()` method, which obviously clears the list. The important thing here is that it calls `delete` for every list element. This means that the property **must** have been created by calling `new`. And of course you should **not** call `delete` yourself, after calling `AddProperty()`.

The documentation for `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::AddProperty()` is rather confusing (or even wrong) imo: *Don't destroy the properties or allow them to go out of scope before the grid control is destroyed.* The property object is allocated in the heap, and the pointer (obtained by `new`) isn't smart, so nothing happens if it just goes out of scope. You can make an easy test, instead of `CMFCPropertyGridProperty` define and create a derived class, with the destructor sending some output to a log file, or calling `TRACE()` (you must run your app in debug mode to see these) - this way you can test if a your property elements are properly destroyed.